# Using typescript in the existing project that has .js files

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an existing `NodeJS` project, which has `.js` files, written in `ES6`. Now I want to start using `typescript` in the existing project. How should I go about? Should I just start with `.ts` files in the same directory structure?

One of the problems I noticed, is that `tsc` only considers the `.ts` files. So for `tsconfig.json` which looks something like:

```
    {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "include": [
        "app/"
    ] 
}
```

will only convert the `.ts` files and leave the other `.js` files that form the majority of the project. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add typescript as developer dependency
by using this command to your project directory

`npm i --save-dev typescript`

Then you convert all .js files to .ts files and then run this command.
`<your_project_path>/node_modules/.bin/tsc -p '<your_project_path>/tsconfig.json'`

Remember to give absolute paths so that there won't be any ambiguity

After you run this command it will create `.js` files in your `./dist` folder. This is your output path given in `"outDir": "./dist` in your `tsconfig.json` file. It will keep the same directory structure which was in your `app` but with `.js` and `.map` files.

I would recommend to use `app/` folder to write all your code in typescript and while deploying run javascript files from `./dist` folder ignoring the `.map` files.

Comment: What is the use of `.map` files?

Comment: You can find your answer over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493738/what-is-a-typescript-map-file