# Node.JS + TypeScript how I can track the source code from the stack trace?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

As I understand typescript will be transpiled to JavaScript and if something inside of my code will throw an error it will contain the stack trace with line numbers of JavaScript not TypeScript. Is any libraries, plugins exists to solve this problem for production running instance? 
I know that for web we have map.js files is something the similar exist for node.js?

Comment: This might bring you into the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493738/what-is-a-typescript-map-file

Comment: I know about map files but how to use them for production stack-trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your app using [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node), not node directly.